# how to create a copy of a database in hive without selecting individual tables?

Tags: database, hive, hql

Is it possible to make a copy of a database in hive?? One method I know is two steps:
1. create NEWDB
2. 
CREATE TABLE NEWDB.NEW_TABLE1 AS select * from OLDDB.OLD_TABLE1;
CREATE TABLE NEWDB.NEW_TABLE2 AS select * from OLDDB.OLD_TABLE2;

but what if you have 500 tables?? or may be more??

Answer (score 0):

Try using Use IMPORT feature of Hive [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual%20ImportExport)